# GridView Item Selection Color change

Tags: flutter, gridview

I have a GridView. I want to change the background color of Card and show the tick mark on that Card when click on any index. Please explain this with simple example. Below is the sample image which I want to implement.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
int checkedIndex = 0;

List cardNames = [
  'Sports',
  'Wild Life',
  'Night',
  'LandSpace',
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      itemCount: cardNames.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return buildCard(index);
      },
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget buildCard(int index) {
  bool checked = index == checkedIndex;
  String name = cardNames[index];
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        checkedIndex = index;
      });
    },
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Card(
            color: checked ? Colors.orange : Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            child: Container(
              child: Center(child: Text(name)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 12,
          right: 12,
          child: Offstage(
            offstage: !checked,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(width: 2),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.check,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I have edited the answer, just set checkedIndex initial value to 0